# GitLab: New Group Button is missing

Tags: git, gitlab

I am new to git and GitLab and using my organization GitLab account, I'm learning to fork and for that I've to create a New Group(according to the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zab2WsNqy6A&list=PLhW3qG5bs-L8YSnCiyQ-jD8XfHC2W1NL_&index=3), I'm following) but the button to add group is missing.

Do I need permission to add new group?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you are [creating a top-level group](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html#instance-wide-user-permissions):

> By default, users can create top-level groups and change their usernames

For subgroups (within an existing group like your organization group), this is related to [issue 25805](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/25805).

The original workaround was:

> - fork a repository to another name space (group or other), then
> - rename the project and also the repository in the Advanced Settings.

- Then transfer the project back to the original namespace (group).

But if you cannot create another namespace, another workaround would be:

> - click import-project
> - select repo-by-url
> - paste your repo url from gitlab
> - set project name and settings
> - if repo is private, add you credentials